# Change keyboard layout (Dvorak, Qwerty, etc.) in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, settings, dvorak

How does one change the keyboard layout from [Qwerty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) to another layout such as [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard)?

I looked in:

- Settings > Region & Language
- Settings > Keyboard
- Help > Ubuntu Desktop Guide > Search

But I found no clue about how to change keyboard layout.

I tried searching for `English` in the `Region & Language` settings. But no `Dvorak` option appears, nor any other Qwerty or other layout — contrary to [this posting](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide that may help you:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Nope, no option appears for Dvorak when searching for English language. See screenshot added to Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well that's unusual. Dvorak is working for me on Linux Mint. Try moving your post over to https://askubuntu.com/ and they may know better.

Comment: Okay, I did [post there](https://askubuntu.com/q/1157633/256002). Thanks.